# Drupal 7.x - Webforms and nodes

Tags: webforms

I am using the webforms module and created a new webform.
Now my problem is... after I have created a specific content type, I would like to diplay this webform...

Imagine: Create a new event with title, start, end und location.

After this, Visitors should see the webform below:

webform contains attend=yes/no, name, email and a submit button that sends an email.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to use the same webform for all your node events?

Then maybe you should consider creating a url pointing to your webform with parameters. In your webform you can catch the parameters with %get[parameter].

Although I should warn you that when I tried something similar I had this problem: [Ampersand does not get urlencoded and breaks my GET parameters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/ampersand-does-not-get-urlencoded-and-breaks-my-get-parameters)

Comment: Yes, one webform for all node events.

can I handover e.g. the event title to the webform?

Comment: Yes you can. In my scenario I had a View that displayed a table with available events along with a link to register to the event. The link was created dynamically using views. If your webform is name "registration" then you should link to it like this [site_link]/registration?t=[title]&d=[date]. You can add as I told you hidden components to your webform to grab the parameters from the url.